# Java design, calling the associated business logic/service

Tags: java

I have 3 objects, a DTO called `BalanceDTO` which implements a interface `RequestDTO` and a `Balance` Entity. I created the DTO because the entity I can't use, JAXB compliance (legacy code).

The DTO is used in the web service layer, `BalanceService`, and the Entity in the API I integrate to from the web service. Between the web service and the API there is validation. `RequestValidation` which has sub validations for each type of `RequestDTO` i.e. `BalanceRequestValidation`.

The validation component takes in a `RequestDTO` as a parameter and then needs to do validation for the specific component. At the point of input the validation component doesn't know which object has been passed to it i.e. `BalanceDTO`, it only sees the interface.

I want to avoid using instanceof so I was thinking of using a visitor on the DTO so that it delegates itself to the validation that needs to be performed on it.

But the validation needs more/other components as well not just the `BalanceDTO` as input parameters and different validations needs different input params.

Is there another way to know which object you are working with and the validation to choose without using instanceof? Another design that I can follow?

Comment: Maybe generics will help? Can you make RequestValidation a generic type with a type parameter? (Example: class RequestValidation<T extends RequestDTO> { ... } / class BalanceRequestValidation extends RequestValidation<BalanceDTO> { ... })

Comment: I'm in control of the validation components so I can do that. My only concern is that the creation of the validation is separated, so it needs to know which 'RequestDTO' object it is working with to choose the specific validation. I want to try and avoid instanceof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are well on the right track here - the Visitor design pattern is often the best way to avoid downcasting.

I am going to suggest a combination of the `visitor` and `delegation` design patterns, though let's walk through some alternatives.

Having the object do the validation itself via the `RequestDTO` interface is not viable since you need different components and the validation is not trivial in nature.

Using `instanceof` and downcasting looks a little messy, and the compiler won't complain if you add a new validatable class and forget to add the validator - you'll be relying on a runtime error via `...else { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown RequestDTO subtype!"); }`

The `visitor` design pattern is the classic way to avoid downcasting plus it also gives you a compiler error if you add a new class that should be validatable and forget to add the validation.

You can use `accept()` and `visit()` methods, or you can use method naming that is closer to your domain, e.g. `validate()`, like this:

```
public interface RequestDTO {
    boolean validate(RequestValidation validator);
}

public class BalanceDTO implements RequestDTO {
    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean validate(RequestValidation validator) {
        return validator.validate(this);
    }
}

public class RequestValidation {
    // components...

    public boolean validate(BalanceDTO balanceDTO) {
        return true;    // todo...
    }

    public boolean validate(AnotherDTO anotherDTO) {
        return true;    // todo...
    }
}
```

If you want to go a bit further you can `delegate` the validation to specific validation components, like this:

```
public class RequestValidation {
    BalanceRequestValidation balanceRequestValidation;
    AnotherRequestValidation anotherRequestValidation;

    public boolean validate(BalanceDTO balanceDTO) {
        return balanceRequestValidation.validate(balanceDTO, a, b, c);
    }

    public boolean validate(AnotherDTO anotherDTO) {
        return anotherRequestValidation.validate(anotherDTO, x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Given I have understood your problem correctly, the `visitor` design pattern, possibly combined with the `delegation` design pattern, is indeed a good approach.

Comment: Thanks @vikingsteve Good example and explanation. What can be done when you cannot change/modify the DTO's to be compliant with the visitor i.e. have the visit or accept method.

Comment: They are being moved outside of my project and out of my control. And it might be hard to convince the arch on there side to log a change request. Other clients also use the code and they only want to use it as a DTO.

Comment: I was asking about the keyword `final`, but ok, if you can't change the DTO's then you can't use the `visitor` pattern in this way :( Naturally, if the DTO class is not `final`, you can derive a subclass, e.g. `class ValidatableBalanceDTO extends BalanceDTO implements RequetDTO`, but then you will need to write a copy constructor (or use reflection utils, or delegate all the methods). And now you have 3 classes for balances: `Balance`, `BalanceDTO`, `ValidatableBalanceDTO` - to be honest it's getting complicated by this point. Back to the drawing board? Perhaps revisit `instanceof`?